# Apollo Explorer Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl-certificate, apollo-server

I am running an Apollo Server with express to create an http server:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({ ... });

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

// enable pre-flight for cors requests
app.options('*', cors());

// Create the HTTP server
let httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen({ port: config.port });
```

Locally I can run the server and query it on Apollo Explorer without any issues.

However, when I deploy this server on dev environment, and try to access the Explorer page with the dev endpoint, I get a few errors.
The app.options() line with cors argument somehow seems to have solved part of them but not all.

Errors I am getting (on Dev Tools console):

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
> POST https://dev.endpoint.service/graphql net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Errors I am getting (as popups on the Explorer page):

> Unable to reach server

> To diagnose the problem, please run:
> npx diagnose-endpoint@1.0.12 --endpoint=https://dev.endpoint.service/graphql

I've tried running the command as instructed in the error and got this result:

> Diagnosing https://dev.endpoint.service/graphql
> Could not find any problems with the endpoint. Would you please to let us know about this > at explorer-feedback@apollographql.com

Frankly, I'm not even sure I understand the problem.
Am I getting these errors because, even though I launch an http server of Apollo without certificates, I am trying to access it via an https endpoint (which requires certificates)? I have to do this, service is stored in AKS cluster, which is only accessible through the endpoint I am calling. But every service that is already there is also an http service, not https, and is accessible through this same endpoint.

Also, even though these errors are showing up frequently, I am also able to query the server successfully most of the time on Explorer, and the data returned is exactly what I expected, which makes even less sense.

I am using edge browser but also tried chrome, and have the same issues.

How can an error like this be intermittent?
[image]

Without any intervention on my part, sometimes it's like this:
[image]

Any help, hints, ideas, please.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As much as it pains me to admit, it seems the issue is related to the VPN my company is using.
There were a few tells that pointed in this direction, once I started paying attention:

1. We can't access the endpoint I mentioned without the VPN turned on.
2. Other services in the AKS behave with the same error, if being called constantly through the same endpoint. I did not think to do that test at first, but when I realized that on Apollo server, the server is constantly doing the introspection thing to check the schema, it means it is being called more often than the other services that do not have this functionality.
3. We have some monitoring tools, to check the pod statuses and so on, and nothing indicated any problems in this service, or that it needed any kind of pod escalation (due to excessive number of requests).
4. I actually performed kubectl portforward test linking my localhost directly to the AKS cluster. Calling the service this way bypasses that endpoint which I am, under normal circumstances, forced to use before the request actually reaches the cluster. And I was simultaneously seeing on one window where I was calling the service the normal way showing that error on Apollo Studio, and at the same time on another Apollo Studio window performing the same request with this portforward bypass mechanic, and the latter was working just fine. If it really was a problem with the service, it would be down for both windows.
5. Other colleagues were testing the service at the same time as me and they were saying the service was working fine for them, until it wasn't. So every developer on my team could be accessing the service at the same time, and the error would just randomly show up for some, but not for others.
6. There are long periods where the error doesn't occur at all, like during lunch hours, or after work hours, and I assume the VPN traffic will be much lower during those hours.